# How can I add the Remarks, Committers and Developers in Jenkins pipeline webhook for office365Connector

Tags: jenkins, groovy, office365connectors

I have set up the office365Connector in a pipeline like so.. How to add the auto Remarks like
Started by an SCM change or Started by User SoAndSo..
and how to add the Committers and Developers..

```
post{
  success{
    office365ConnectorSend(
        status: "Build Success",
        webhookUrl: "Url",
        color: '00ff00',
        message: "Some Message"
        )  
      
    }
    failure{
         office365ConnectorSend(
        status: "Build Failed",
        webhookUrl: "UrL",
        color: 'ff4000',
        message: "The build has failed, please check build logs"
        )
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

If you want to @mention someone, that's still not available by the office365 plugin for jenkins

To get the user that started the build, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194316/how-to-get-the-build-user-in-jenkins-when-job-triggered-by-timer)

To get the committer's email, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256083/github-plugin-for-jenkins-get-committer-and-author-name)

If you really want to mention users, as I do, you can:

- if you know java, create a PR that solves this [issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/office-365-connector-plugin/issues/55) on the official repo
- if you don't know java, or can't spare the time, you will have to hack things together:

1. This is how you would use [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497385/how-to-make-a-curl-request-with-json-in-jenkins-pipeline-groovy-script?rq=1) from a pipeline
2. Now you have to get the user is from the [User graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#json-representation)
3. Add the webhook as a credential on jenkins, like this:
   [image]

So you can invoke it in the pipeline:

```
office365ConnectorSend message: "Hello", webhookUrl: credentials("wh-msteams-dev")
```

4. Send an [adaptive card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#sample-adaptive-card-with-a-mention), which is the only type that supports mentions at the moment, here's a sample from the docs:

```
{
  "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
  "content": {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Hi <at>John Doe</at>"
      }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0",
    "msteams": {
      "entities": [
        {
          "type": "mention",
          "text": "<at>John Doe</at>",
          "mentioned": {
            "id": "29:123124124124",
            "name": "John Doe"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

No, this is not trivial.

Yes, I'm also in pain by how bad this mention is achieved.

Disappointed, but not surprised. This is **Microsoft** Teams after all.

Please surive.